# Why don't feeds get automatically imported?

Tags: 8, feeds

I am using the Feeds module, and set the import period to once a day. The site  cron tasks run every hour, but I noticed that feeds don't get imported automatically. Manually importing them works fine.

How do I automatically import them?

Comment: Maybe there is an issue with one of the feed types. Do you have more than one feed? Maybe one is blocking the rest. See https://www.drupal.org/node/2788177

Comment: @MegaChriz thanks for reply. Yes feeds are more than one but I don't get anything in logs. No clue where is problem. But when one feed type manually import except they imported with this error `The file, , Failed to save because the extension, Is invalid.`

Comment: If an import fails with a fatal error then it is not possible to log that error in Drupal's database log, but the error should be logged by the server. Check the error logs on the server. If the error happens on production, ask your hosting provider where you can find these logs.

Comment: Well don't get any fetal error Or any log details:(